# Bootstrap Automatically Hiding my images in my Webpage Php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm showing my data in an inline manner using bootstrap like this
for example,[image]

But when I add some bootstrap classed, then my images are not showing.
My Code is :

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Teachers:</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            $queryTeachers = "SELECT places.PLACE_NAME,teacher_status.PERSON_NAME,DATE_FORMAT(teacher_status.STATUS_DATE,'%d-%m-%Y') as STATUS_DATE,DATE_FORMAT(teacher_status.STATUS_TIME,'%h:%i:%s %p') as STATUS_TIME, teachers.IMAGE_FOLDER AS IMAGE_FOLDER,teachers.IMAGE_NAME as IMAGE_NAME FROM places,teacher_status,teachers WHERE places.PLACE_ID=teacher_status.PERSON_CURRENT_PLACE AND teachers.TEACHER_ID=teacher_status.TEACHER_ID;";
            $resultTeachers = mysqli_query($conn,$queryTeachers) or die("Unable to select status". mysqli_error($conn));
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTeachers)) {
                echo '<div class="col-lg-3">';
                echo '<img src="'."../".$row['IMAGE_FOLDER'].$row['IMAGE_NAME'].'" width="130" height="150"/>';
                echo "<br>";
                echo "Persone Name : ".ucwords($row['PERSON_NAME']);
                echo "<br>";
                echo "Current Place : ".ucwords($row['PLACE_NAME']);
                echo "<br>";
                echo "Status Date : ".$row['STATUS_DATE'];
                echo "<br>";
                echo "Status Time : ".$row['STATUS_TIME'];
                echo "<br><br>";
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm completely new to bootstrap and only know the basics.

Comment: Line with `echo '<div class="col-lg-3"';` seems to be missing the closing `>`

Comment: ok sorry  . . . adding

Comment: Thanks ... it has been done  . . . thanks alot

Comment: Can you check the image path is right? Try using browser inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Try following code that is for demo only

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Teachers:</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++) {?>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="img-responsive"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"></div>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use fixed height and width in images just use a class ie : img-responsive

eg:- class="img-responsive" in img tag

Comment: i use width and height attribute for images, some of my images has different resolution , so if i used the img-responsive, they are overriding the widht and height property of html and takes whole width and full size image. i tried it .

Comment: Just take a div befor the img tag and fix it's height and width